# Can't perform segue and dismiss

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I can't present a second View with a segue and dismiss the first one afterwards:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TargetLS" sender: self];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I always have multiple modal views on top of each other.

If I put it like the following:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TargetLS" sender: self];
```

I get some weird error codes:

```
2012-01-01 17:23:54.018 Coverdale[21462:f803] *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:], 
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UIWindowController.m:188
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it so far, in `viewDidLoad` i am setting up a new interface for different Orientations:

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
```

etc.

and for orientation changes:

```
 - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
NSLog(@"Rotation");
if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
   {
```

Answer (score 2):

When using modal view you should design the flow of your program use modal view to gather or present information and them return to the view that presented it. You can then present another modal view. If that doesn't work for your program flow you likely need to be using something other than modal view.

Comment: I am trying to have a different interface for landscape and portrait orientation. What kind of segue what you prefer in that case?

Comment: If the function is similar, I would use the same view controller and just hide the portrait view and show the landscape view and vice versa. In that case you would not use a segue at all, but you could still call an animation for the transition.

Comment: Yeah but i want to have completely different view controller … How would i manage to layout them in IB in just one interface?

Comment: @UrbanSeifert When you add a view controller it comes with a view. Give that a name of containerView. In portrait mode, add a uiview to that, use the size inspector to turn off autoresizing, then name it portraitView. Select the view controller again and set the orientation to landscape mode. Select the containerView and add another uiview to it, use the size inspector to turn off autoresizing, then name it landscapeView. You can now show either the landscapeView or portraitView and hide the other as appropriate for the selected orientation.